# Determine if a number is the length of a farey sequence

Tags: farey-sequences

Given a number $j$, is there a way to determine that it is the length of a valid [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence).

The length is given by:

$$|F_n| = \frac{1}{2}(n+3)n - \sum_{d=2}^n |F_\frac{n}{d}|$$

For example, 2, 7, 16875 all valid (lengths of sequence of orders 1, 4, 235), but 4 is invalid, since there is no valid Farey sequence of that length.

For now, I see no option but to compute $|F_n|$ up to $|F_n| <= j$ for $n=1...n$. This approach is fine for small j ($j<10^6$) but becomes unpractical above that. Is there a better way?

Comment: Using $|F_n| = |F_{n-1}| + \phi(n)$ should allow much more efficient computation using a sieve to compute $\phi$, perhaps up to $j<10^12$ or thereabouts. Do you think that's good enough?

Comment: Hm no, I'm looking for $10^{19} <= j <= 10^{20}$